# Number of Iterations Required for a Markov Chain to Reach a Stationary Distribution

Tags: probability

Supposes I have a Discrete Time Markov Chain with Transition Matrix  $P = \begin{pmatrix} p_{11} & p_{12} \\ p_{21} & p_{22} \end{pmatrix}$ and initial distribution $\begin{pmatrix} p^0_1 \\ p^0_2 \end{pmatrix}$.

In this case, we can define the Stationary Distribution  $\begin{pmatrix} \pi_1 \\ \pi_2 \end{pmatrix}$ as:

$$\lim_{{n \to \infty}} \begin{pmatrix} \pi_1 \\ \pi_2 \end{pmatrix}^n = \begin{pmatrix} p^0_1 \\ p^0_2 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} p_{11} & p_{12} \\ p_{21} & p_{22} \end{pmatrix}^n$$

**My Question:** Provided the Stationary Distribution does exist, is it possible to find out the number of iterations $n$ required for the Markov Chain to reach its Stationary Distribution?

Thanks!

Comment: What makes you think that the stationary distribution can be reached in a finite number of steps?

Comment: @ jd27; thank you so much for your reply! I think you are right ... by definition, it is impossible tor each the stationary distribution in a finite number of steps.

Comment: I wonder if it is possible to know: How many iterations (i.e. steps) are required for the stationary distribution to become "close enough" to the actual stationary distribution? i.e. how much will it deviate (epsilon/delta)?

Comment: yes it is possible to find convergence bounds based on the eigenvalues of the transition matrix. For a simple case this is done in the book "Probability Theory" by Achim Klenke in section 18.4. You can probably find information on this on the internet as well, one keyword would be "spectral gap". [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2465079/intuitive-explanation-of-the-spectral-gap-in-context-of-markov-chain-monte-carlo) is related as well.